# USING FileStream and handling its weird exceptions

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io, client-server, system.io.file

The following code works for me when i have a fixed file+filepath declared in my code and is understood to work.

```
  NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();
        string FileName = @"D:\John\FYL\video1.mp4";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName));

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            netStream.CopyTo(fs);
        }
        netStream.Close();
    }
```

But fails for this protion.

```
 NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();
        //  FileName is taken at run time on button click from textbox.

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\John\FYL\"+FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            netStream.CopyTo(fs);
        }
        netStream.Close();
    }
```

Now when i checked another case, using `File.Create` and getting `FileName` at run-time it works.

```
    FileStream output = File.Create(@"D:\John\" + FileName)
```

I'm in doubt because i have to get the saving location at run-time from Browse dialog but why `FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\John\FYL\+FileName` throws exceptions like `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException` and `System.UnauthorizedAcessException` although i changed security settings for my local drives.

Does thread affecting all this as this code is a part of code loaded at run-time and browse is a click event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the directory exists before trying to create the file.

```
NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();

if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\John\FYL\" + FileName)) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\John\FYL\" + FileName);
}

using (FileStream fs = new
    FileStream(@"D:\John\FYL\" + FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    netStream.CopyTo(fs);
}

netStream.Close();
```

You may also want to check that the variable `FileName` is properly formatted. Since you are already providing a trailing backslash `"D:\John\FYL\"`, check that `FileName` is not `\File1.mp4`, which will concatenate into `"D:\John\FYL\\File1.mp4"`, which is incorrect.

Comment: I am using this code in a thread which is started from form_load() .does it should wait for browse_click to create `FileStream()`?.

Comment: Btw what u suggested returned `An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\John\FYL\'.`

Comment: @Khan Are you saying that the code is executed before the `Browse` button is clicked? WHich means that the `FileName` variable is not even loaded yet?

Comment: The `FileName` gets its value from `textBox.text` after `Browse_Click`

Comment: Does this behavior is the result of this action?

Comment: @Khan you did not answer my question. Is the file save code executed BEFORE or AFTER the button is clicked?

Comment: Exactly. You have not specified the `FileName` yet, that's why the file path of `"D:\John\FYL\" + FileName` returns `'D:\John\FYL\'`. You need to check and rethink your logic.

Comment: You're rite and i think the same but why the same is hanldled by `File.Create(@"D:\John\" + FileName)` ?

Comment: @Khan Are you sure a file is created by `File.Create(@"D:\John\" + FileName)`? The variable `FileName` is not even specified, what file is it creating?

Comment: YES,But it's not throwing an exception and working for me atleast and putting me in doubt

Answer (score 1):

have you tried looking at the value of FileName? probably it's giving wrong value.
If File name contains only the name of the file, then be sure to give the name along with file extension, if there isn't any extension provided, your program will treat the name as a directory extension which it is not able to find.

If the File name contains the name along with directory heirarchy then you are simply concatenating one directory to your "D:\John\" directory which again is wrong.